# Contract is being mined but not successfully

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

```
   struct list{
       string typo;  // name of dataset
       address head;
   }

  mapping (string => list) _list;

 struct node{
     address add;
     address next; 
 }

 mapping (string =>mapping(address=>node)) _node;

 function add(string _typo1,address _addr){
        addToList(_typo1);
        addToNodes(_typo1 , _addr);

}

function addToList(string _typo){
    _list[_typo].typo = _typo;
}

function addToNodes(string _typo,address _addr){

    _node[_typo][_addr].next = _addr;
    _node[_typo][_addr].add =_addr;

}
```

Above is the code snippet of the contract I have been trying to make work but somehow I am not getting anywhere. If I call only on function either addToList() or addToNodes() then it works fine but if I call both the same time it won't work.

PS: I am using private testnet here.

gas limitation is not an issue here I tried to provide maximum gas but it won't work.

Comment: I may be out-of-date here but using a string as a mapping key feels icky. Try making your mapping key bytes32 instead of string, and make it with something like _node[keccak256(_typo)][_addr].next = _addr;

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in _typo :-)

"_typo" is undefined in:

```
addToNodes(_typo , _addr);
```

Maybe should be

```
addToNodes(_typo1 , _addr);
```

It looks like you're after something more intricate but I'm unsure of the goal.

Compiles and works:

```
contract X {

  struct list{
       string typo;  // name of dataset
       address head;
   }

  mapping (string => list) _list;

  struct node{
     address add;
     address next; 
  }

  mapping (string =>mapping(address=>node)) _node;

  function add(string _typo1,address _addr){
        addToList(_typo1);
        addToNodes(_typo1 , _addr);
  }

  function addToList(string _typo){
    _list[_typo].typo = _typo;
  }

  function addToNodes(string _typo,address _addr){

    _node[_typo][_addr].next = _addr;
    _node[_typo][_addr].add =_addr;

  }

}
```

In Remix to show it working:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am doing the same as above and blocks are being mined and added to the blockchain but data is not getting updated. So whenever I try to get the data of struct node it returns nothing. Any suggestions on debugging. I tried eth.getTransactionReceipt() but all looks fine there. I am using private chain here.

Comment: You have no getter function(s) to actually retrieve values. I was going to put one together but I got lost in some things that seem to need correction. Can you plainly describe the structure and purpose? I will make it easier hit the mark.